# populating combo box with folders on disk using QFileSystemModel

Tags: pyqt, qcombobox, qfilesystemmodel

Hi I have written this basic code trying to populate folders underneath the `/Users/` directory, but I don't know what I am missing its not populating.

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui 
from PyQt4 import QtCore


class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    """docstring for MyWindow"""
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        fsm = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
        fsm.setRootPath("/Users/")
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        combo = QtGui.QComboBox()
        combo.setModel(fsm)
        layout.addWidget(combo)
        self.setLayout(layout)



def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    win.raise_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am getting a `/` in the comobobox instead of the whole list of folders under `/Users/` directory.

I think its better to use `QFileSystemModel` instead of using `os.listdir` interms of efficiency and will update the view if somebody updates folder or adds folder in the `/Users/` directory !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that `QFileSystemModel` is a hierarchical model, so you need to let the `QComboBox` know which `QModelIndex` represents the children you want to display.  You do that with `QComboBox.setRootModelIndex()`

`QFileSystemModel.setRootPath()` conveniently returns the `QModelIndex` of the path you set.

So a small change is all you need (tested on Windows) -

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui 
from PyQt4 import QtCore


class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    """docstring for MyWindow"""
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        fsm = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
        index = fsm.setRootPath("/Users/")
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        combo = QtGui.QComboBox()
        combo.setModel(fsm)
        combo.setRootModelIndex(index)
        layout.addWidget(combo)
        self.setLayout(layout)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    win.raise_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```